# Work permit for dependent in Germany

Tags: germany, family, working

I have two questions:

1. Whether my spouse can work in a dependent visa?
2. If yes, what is the probability for her to get a job?

Thank you

Comment: What is your nationality, and your immigration status in Germany?

Comment: @user16259 the spouse's nationality may also be relevant.

Comment: @phoog the spouse's skill set might matter for item 2 as well. User15057, it will be difficult or impossible to answer part 2 of your question definitively. Too many uncertainties.

Comment: @user16259 perhaps we should answer this question by assuming that neither spouse is an EU citizen and listing the cases where one's successful sponsorship of the other would result in the second being authorized to work.  I don't know enough about it to know whether that would be practical; do you?  We don't even need to assume that they're not EU citizens, since it would only take a sentence or two to cover the case where they are.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you are a German national, EU citizen or foreign national, basically, if *you* are allowed to work in Germany, any family you bring is allowed, too.

Whether somebody is allowed to work is no longer a permit of it's own, but simply a remark on your "Aufenthaltstitel".

Assuming you are a foreign national, this is a quote from Wikipedia applying to you and your spouse:

> Zu Ausländern nachgezogene Familienangehörige erhalten ein Recht auf Erwerbstätigkeit, soweit der Ausländer, zu dem der Familiennachzug erfolgt, zur Ausübung einer Erwerbstätigkeit berechtigt ist (§ 27 Abs. 5 AufenthG). Sie erhalten anders als bisher sofort ein Recht auf unbeschränkten Zugang zur Beschäftigung, sowie ggf. einen Zugang zu selbständiger Erwerbstätigkeit, wenn der bereits hier lebende Partner diese Rechte besitzt.

Family members that followed foreign nationals to Germany are granted the right to work if the foreign national is allowed to work. Those rights are granted immediately if the partner living in Germany already has those permits.

For obvious reasons I cannot comment on the probability of somebody *actually getting a job*. That depends on too many factors of which *none* are known.